# java.sql.SQLException: [TimesTen]Cannot find the requested DSN (ormb_ttdb) in ODBCINI /var/TimesTen/tt1122/sys.odbc.ini or /var/TimesTen/sys.odbc.ini

Tags: unix, jdbc, timesten

I have setup a **Timesten** **client(11.2.2.8.0)** on my **unix** machine.

I have setup a Timesten server on different machine.

After setup is complete I am trying to connect to Timesten database using **JDBC** from my spark code written in java.

I am getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [TimesTen][TimesTen 11.2.2.8.0 CLIENT]Cannot find the requested DSN (ormb_ttdb) in ODBCINI /var/TimesTen/tt1122/sys.odbc.ini or  /var/TimesTen/sys.odbc.ini
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:3237)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:3386)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:3351)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:800)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.connect(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1866)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:305)
        at com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver.connect(TimesTenDriver.java:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
        at com.sample.Transformation.main(Transformation.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have set correct values of **TTC_SERVER** and **TTC_SERVER_DSN** in `sys.odbc.ini` file at `/var/TimesTen` and `/var/TimesTen/tt1122` locations.

Can someone explain the reason?

**EDIT**

**sys.odbc.ini**

```
# Copyright (c) 1999, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. 

########################################################################
# This following sample definitions should be in the .odbc.ini file
# that is used for the TimesTen 11.2.2 Client.
# The Server Name is set in the TTC_SERVER attribute.
# The Server DSN is set in the TTC_SERVER_DSN attribute.
#########################################################################

[ODBC Data Sources]
#sampledbCS_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2 Client Driver
#cachedb1CS_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2 Client Driver
#repdb1CS_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2 Client Driver
#repdb2CS_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2 Client Driver

#[sampledbCS_1122]
TTC_SERVER=<SERVER's HOSTTNAME>
TTC_SERVER_DSN=ormb_ttdb

#[cachedb1CS_1122]
#TTC_SERVER=SERVER's HOSTTNAME
#TTC_SERVER_DSN=cachedb1_1122

#[repdb1CS_1122]
#TTC_SERVER=SERVER's HOSTTNAME
#TTC_SERVER_DSN=repdb1_1122

#[repdb2CS_1122]
#TTC_SERVER=SERVER's HOSTTNAME
#TTC_SERVER_DSN=repdb2_1122
```

**My connection String in spark code :**

```
String ttConnection = "jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=<DSN_NAME>;UID=<USER_NAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>";
```

Comment: Please show the contents of those `sys.odbc.ini` files

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have added contents of sys.odbc.ini files

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Yes, you don't have a definition for the `ormb_ttdb` DSN, as indicated in the error message. I also hope you realise that `#` is a comment mark in `ini` files.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have entry for ormb_ttdb in actual file, i have just replaced it here for the display purpose. I understand # is a comment and first two entries are not commented for same purpose

Comment: The second entry **is** commented, in ini files, section are started with `[name-of-section]`, and the second section is commented out. And really, your question should be consistent. If the error complains about `ormb_ttdb`, then you shouldn't rename it from the file (by all means, anonymize the config value, but the entry should be there).

Comment: You have **no** DSN entries in that file, because all sections (except `ODBC Data Sources`) are commented out.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel TTC_SERVER=<SERVER's HOSTTNAME>
TTC_SERVER_DSN=ormb_ttdb These are uncommented entrues which specifies DSN.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel for sampledbCS_1122 I have uncommented entries.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the ini-file format. The line `#[sampledbCS_1122]` means that section is commented out, which makes those config values part of the `[ODBC Data Sources]` section where they are meaningless.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I am not very familiar with .ini files you are right so should I uncomment #[sampledbCS_1122]  and try?

Comment: Yes you should uncomment that, and possibly also its entry under `[ODBC Data Sources]`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks sure I will do that, do I have to change [sampledbCS_1122]  this name to something else or it doesnt matter?

Comment: That is the local DSN name that you should use in your connection string.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so my connection string will be like : String ttConnection = "jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=sampledbCS_1122;UID=<USER_NAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>"; instead of String ttConnection = "jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=ormb_ttdb;UID=<USER_NAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>"; , is it so?

Comment: I suggest you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21638/writing_app.htm#TTJDV128)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sure thanks

Comment: After using connection String : jdbc:timesten:client:dsn=sampledbCS_1122;UID=<USER_NAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD> , I am getting error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)......

Comment: @MarkRotteveel LD_LIBRARY_PATH is already set on client. still getting va.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDriver

Comment: @MarkRotteveel do i need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on server as well?